# Meaning of "Rejection of something FOR something else" in Stoner by John Williams

Tags: meaning

In this paragraph of Stoner by John Williams:

> Walker nodded and began swiftly to speak. "I intend to trace Shelley's
> first **rejection of** Godwinian necessitarianism **for** a more or less
> Platonic ideal, in the 'Hymn to Intellectual Beauty,' through the
> mature use of that ideal, in Prometheus Unbound, as a comprehensive
> synthesis of his earlier atheism, radicalism, Christianity, and
> scientific necessitarianism, and ultimately to account for the decay
> of the ideal in such a late work as Hellas.

What does "**rejection of** Godwinian necessitarianism **for** a more or less Platonic ideal" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that Shelley stopped believing in Godwinian necessitarianism and started believung in a more or leas Platonic ideal.

It means that Shelly replace his belief in Godwinian necessitarianism with a different belief, belief in a more or less Platonic ideal.